# Rails 3 Locale switches when using different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, webrick, unicorn

I've got a Rails 3.2.3 app with the `default_locale` set to `:nl`. When I start the app using Thin or Unicorn, the app's locale is set to `:en`. When I use Webrick, the locale is correctly set to `:nl`.

This change is triggered by a commit that updates several third-party gems, although I have not been able to single out any one gem upgrade in particular -- I can reverse each of them individually and get the same result. However, when I checkout the offending commit's parent, all is well too.

When I run the app on a remote server in production mode, it all works fine, so it seems to be local to my machine.

I have removed every single installed gem and re-installed them all, which made no difference.

Does anyone have any idea what might trigger this behaviour? And especially why using webrick or unicorn would make a difference?

**Edit**: I have pinpointed the bug to be triggered by upgrading Draper from 0.11 to 0.12 ([issue at Github](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper/issues/202)). Not sure if it is also the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to track this problem down to a bad practice in my own Rails app that caused a bug by upgrading the Draper gem. There's a [full explanation in the Draper documentation](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper#a-note-on-rails-configuration).

Answer (score 0):

http://labs.revelationglobal.com/2009/11/13/unicorn_and_i18n.html

Comment: Unicorn might remember locale setting across requests, but this problem is not solved by rebooting unicorn or switching to thin. It _is_ solved by switching to webrick. This link seems unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has occured to me before wich was triggered by the "active_admin" gem you might want to use an earlier version to prevent this, I do not really know wich one so you can play around with it a little.

another option would be to set the active_admin locale in a before_filter,

```
config.before_filter :set_admin_locale
```

And set_admin_locale is in the application_controller:

```
def set_admin_locale
  I18n.locale = :nl
end
```

hope it helped

Comment: I do not use active_admin. Do you of any other gems that trigger the same behavior?

Comment: Just check your configuration files if there is an locale dependency for any of your gems thats how I figured out.